# Creating class inside package A of A.B in IntelliJ

Tags: intellij-idea, package

I have a maven project in IntelliJ IDE. I have created a package with name `event.handlers`. After which I created multiple classes inside this package. 
There are no classes inside `event` everything is inside `event.handlers`.
Now I want to create a java class inside package `event`.

Is there any way from the IDE I can do that? 
Currently, I am manually creating the java file inside the `event` folder in my code repository.

Comment: I usually then right-click the parent package, and name the class "event.ClassName". IntelliJ will create the class in the package event.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In the left Project structure pane, there is Settings button, in that please Uncheck, ***Compact Empty Middle Packages***.

The settings will be like

[image: this].

Now you will have a tree structure, where you can right-click or (ctrl + enter/ alt + insert) on the package and create the file.

For example,

[image]

Comment: You need to check **Flatten Packages** first to be able to uncheck **Compact Empty Middle Packages**. You can then uncheck **Flatten Packages** again.

Answer (score 2):

Try creating a `Java Class` at `src` folder named `event.NewClass`. This will create a `NewClass.java` inside `src/event`.

You can create folder with the dot symbol `.` at creating a `Java Class` or a `Package`, or `Kotlin File/Class` when `Type` is not `File`. For example create a `Package` with name `com.company.example` at `src` folder will automatically generate the folders recursively, `src/com/company/example`, create a `Java Class` with name `com.company.example.AClass` will automatically generate a file `AClass.java` inside the automatically generated folder tree `src/com/company/example`.

Answer (score 0):

It might be easier to just create the class inside package `AB` and `Refactor > Move` to place it inside of `A`.

It seems that all other answers here are workarounds anyway, so if it's just a one-off, this might be the easiest option.

However, in my case, after doing this I had to "Invalidate Caches and Restart" before IDEA updated the UI properly.